# Does Context.Done() unblock when context variable goes out of scope in golang?

Tags: go

Will context.Done() unblock when a context variable goes out of scope and cancel is not explicitly called?

Let's say I have the following code:

```
func DoStuff() {
    ctx, _ := context.WithCancel(context.Background())
    go DoWork(ctx)
    return
}
```

Will ctx.Done() unblock in DoWork after the return in DoStuff()?

I found this thread, https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/golang-nuts/BbvTlaQwhjw, where the person asking how to use Context.Done() claims that context.Done() will unblock when the context variable leaves scope but no one validated this, and I didn't see anything in the docs.

Comment: I think the person who you think suggested this was just asking a question about whether it's cancelled automatically rather than claiming anything.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, it doesn't cancel automatically when the context leaves scope. Typically one calls `defer cancel()` (using the callback from `ctx.WithCancel()`) oneself to make sure that the context is cancelled.

https://blog.golang.org/context provides a good overview of how to use contexts correctly (including the `defer` pattern above). Also, the source code https://golang.org/src/context/context.go is quite readable and you can see there's no magic that would provide automatic cancellation.

Answer (score 2):

"Unblocking" is not the clearest terminology. `Done()` returns a channel (or nil) that will receive a `struct{}` and/or close when the context is "cancelled". What exactly that chan is, or when it is sent on, is up to the individual implementation. It may be sent/closed at some fixed time as with `WithDeadline`, or manually done as with `WithCancel`.

The key though, is that this is never "automatic" or guaranteed to happen. If you make a context with `WithCancel` and read from the `Done()` channel, that read will block **indefinitely** until the `Cancel()` method is called. If that never happens, then you have a wasted goroutine and your application's memory will increase each time you do it.

Once the context is completely out of scope (no executing goroutine is listening to it or has a reference to the parent context), it will get garbage collected and everything will go away.

**EDIT**: After reading the source though, it looks like [WithCancel](https://golang.org/src/context/context.go#L229) and friends spawn goroutines to propigate the cancellation. Therefore you **must** make sure Cancel gets called at some point to avoid goroutine leaks.